# Resizing before Uploading in PHP SWF Uploader Overlay DEMO

Tags: php, ajax, flash, overlay, swfupload

How to add the facility "resize image before upload" in SWF Overlay Demo.

http://demo.swfupload.org/v250beta3/resizedemo/index.php

http://demo.swfupload.org/v220/overlaydemo/index.php

I want this resizing facility(1st link) in overlay demo(2nd). Could you please help?

is it  possible to get  "image resizing before upload"  in the second link ?

Comment: It is unclear, but if you want to use the SWFuploader to do this, I don't think it can. You will need to add in some facility to resize on the client and then upload the new file data.

Comment: I hope the question is clear now.

Answer (score 0):

They way I've done it is I let the user upload the image to a temporary location using this ajax flash uploader... http://valums.com/ajax-upload/

The flash uploads to a php script that creates 2 temporary version, the first one a  resized version and the second the original.  Then I return a json response with the path to the temporary files.

Then I load the resized version amd  use this cropping  http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop.html with a ratio constraint to get the portion of the picture to capture.

To complete the process the user submits the selected coordinates and the path to the temporary images to another scirpt which then takes the coordinates maps them to the original image and extract the portion of the image and resize it to the desired size using GD.

Comment: Googled a bit and found that you can only access local files as of flash 10+. This article shows how to create a thumb from a local file... http://techblog.floorplanner.com/2009/05/04/load-modify-and-save-local-images-with-flash-player-10/  I guess this is similar to what you want to do...

Comment: thanks for the answer. I wil dfntly use it in my other projects. But Now I want the resizing facility in my SWL Overlay... can u pls tell is there anyway I can do that?

Comment: Found these 2 solutions that allow you to resize a file before it's being uploaded 1. plupload http://www.plupload.com/index.php and 2. http://www.aurigma.com/

Comment: here is another: http://www.shift8creative.com/projects/agile-uploader/index.html

Comment: thank you so much for your support... I have done it in swf upload itself by editing its code. but i like the last solution you provided...  thank you so much.